# How to add script on Wordpress admin post update or create post button?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am looking for add a custom script to check if my post tile, body has any special characters in it. I want to add the code on Update button on Post edit page.
[add script on Update button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUkCx.png)

I have added a admin-script which is running on admin pages but unable to add the script on the button.

Is there any other way to check if the post tile contains any special characters so that it prevent to save

Comment: Hi Susnata and welcome to SO. It might be a lot easier to remove the special characters before updating the post so that it's not possible to have any special characters. [This post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134664/what-is-correct-way-to-hook-when-update-post) on the WP StackExchange has a list of hooks which you can use to filter your title and body values.

Comment: Thanks! But I am really a novice on WordPress, can you give an example link where i can check the implementation?